# MS Outlook - Change The Hyperlink Tooltip

Tags: hyperlink, outlook, tooltip

Does anyone have an idea how I could change the displayed tooltip when a mouse hovers over a hyperlink in an email?

Answer (score 0):

The screentip can be set with Word's Hyperlinks.Add method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837214%28v=office.15%29.aspx

expression .Add(Anchor, Address, SubAddress, ScreenTip, TextToDisplay, Target)

This describes how you use Hyperlinks.Add in Outlook.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx

```
strLink = "http://www.outlookcode.com"
strLinkText = "Get Outlook code samples here"
Set objInsp = objMsg.GetInspector

If objInsp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then  ' <===

    Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
    Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection
    If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatPlain Then
        objDoc.Hyperlinks.Add objSel.Range, strLink, _
                          "", "", strLinkText, ""
    Else
        objSel.InsertAfter strLink
    End If

End If
```